# Capture input and direct output from and to desktop using Haskell?

Tags: linux, haskell, io, output, user-input

I have a program which effectively shuffles the keys on the keyboard, remapping them randomly so each one corresponds to a different output than it normally produces.

My issue is that I am only capturing keys inputted to the terminal the program runs in, and likewise only outputting to that same terminal. What I would like to achieve is capturing and transforming all keystrokes across the desktop and outputting the transformed key where it was originally input while the program runs.

Here is my main loop.

```hs
main = do                                                                                           
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering                                                                   
  hSetEcho stdout False
                                                                             
  s <- shuffle keys                                                                                 
  displayKeys s                                                                                     
  putStrLn ""                                                                                       
                                                                                                    
  let                                                                                               
    typeLoop = do                                                                                   
      c <- getChar                                                                                  
      let shuf_tuples = zip keys s                                                                  
          new_key     = reMap c shuf_tuples                                                         
                                                                                                    
      putChar $ fromMaybe ' ' new_key                                                               
                                                                                                    
      typeLoop                                                                                      
                                                                                                    
  typeLoop
```

This program is intended as a prototype for typing secure information like passwords so security considerations both in the solution and existing implementation are appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and would prefer the solutions requiring the least packages (if possible). Would not mind fully portable solutions either as it may help other people. If I can put in another preference: I am learning Haskell and would favor a 'from scratch' approach even if it sacrifices portability.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/kmonad/kmonad

Comment: @Noughtmare ooh, that looks like a nice tool!

Comment: This is not a job for Haskell, and I say that as the author of a [Haskell tool to globally capture keys](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spartacon), so I'm somewhat familiar with the space. Instead, use `setxkbmap`.